# How to get the filename showed in a toast.maketext

Tags: android, text, gallery, toast

I made some experiments with the gallery to learn how to use it and I need to understand how I can get the filename showed by the Toast.maketext instead of the position number I tried to use getString but the emulator stops after loading the app.
Here's my code maybe someone got the same problem and can suggest me a new way to get the part of the file after R.drawable.

> public class DisplayViewsExample extends Activity
>   {
>       //---the images to display---
>       Integer[] imageIDs = {
>               R.drawable.slovenia,
>               R.drawable.peru,
>               R.drawable.canarie,
>               R.drawable.lanzarote,
>               R.drawable.casasco,
>               R.drawable.avid,
>               R.drawable.danimarca,
>               R.drawable.eritrea
>       };

```
@Override    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.displayview);

    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);

    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));        
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, 
        View v, int position, long id) 
        {              

            //---display the images selected---
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);                
            imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context context;
    private int itemBackground;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        context = c;
        //---setting the style---
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        itemBackground = a.getResourceId(
            R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();                    
    }

    //---returns the number of images---
    public int getCount() {
        return imageIDs.length;
    }

    //---returns the ID of an item--- 
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }            

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //---returns an ImageView view---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(120, 150));
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

}

Thank you
Angelo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Resources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) class has methods: `public String getResourceEntryName (int resid)` and `public String getResourceName (int resid)` from which you can get resouce name from resourceID.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {              
        //---display the images selected---
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);                
        imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                "pic: " + getBaseContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(imageIDs[position]) + " selected", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know such a method. I succeeded to get the result writing an other String [] array with different titles for the picture shown in the gallery. Of course, it is more complicated to set the name in the exact sequence to match the picture position but I could add in this way a complete title to each picture. I will take note of your suggestion and save it ot use in my next work. I appreciated a lot your help.